# Adding an increase / decrease speed button to slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a slideshow that has an 'increase speed', 'decrease speed' button as well as pause/play. Im having a hard time and getting confused with the timeout/interval usage.

script:

```
// creates array and holds images
var imageArray = ['img/br1.jpg', 'img/br2.jpg', 'img/br3.png', 'img/br4.gif', 'img/br5.jpeg', 'img/br6.jpeg', 'img/br7.jpeg'];
// set the array to start at 0
var i = 0;

// create function 'slideShow'
function slideShow() {
// creates variable 'div' to load images into a div selected using 'getElementById'
var div = document.getElementById('slideshowdiv');
div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" />';

//increment i by 1
i++;

// checks if i is greater than or equal to the length
if(i >= imageArray.length) {
    // if true, resets value to 0
    i = 0;
};
// every 2 seconds change image
timer = setTimeout('slideShow()', 2000);
};


function stopShow() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
};
function playShow() {
    timer = setTimeout('slideShow()', 2000);
};
function increase() {

};
function decrease() {

};
```

html:

```
<body onload="slideShow();">
<div id="slideshowdiv"></div>
<div class="change">
<button onclick="stopShow()">Stop</button>
<button onclick="playShow()">Play</button>
<button onclick="increase()">Speed up slideshow</button>
<button onclick="decrease()">Slow down slideshow</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to change the fixed value with a var:

```
// creates array and holds images
var imageArray = ['img/br1.jpg', 'img/br2.jpg', 'img/br3.png', 'img/br4.gif', 'img/br5.jpeg', 'img/br6.jpeg', 'img/br7.jpeg'];
// set the array to start at 0
var i = 0;

var speed = 2000;
var minSpeed = 3000;
var maxSpeed = 0;

// create function 'slideShow'
function slideShow() {
// creates variable 'div' to load images into a div selected using 'getElementById'
var div = document.getElementById('slideshowdiv');
div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" />';

//increment i by 1
i++;

// checks if i is greater than or equal to the length
if(i >= imageArray.length) {
    // if true, resets value to 0
    i = 0;
};
// every 2 seconds change image
timer = setTimeout('slideShow()', speed);
};


function stopShow() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
};
function playShow() {
    timer = setTimeout('slideShow()', speed);
};
function increase() {
  if(speed -100 > maxSpeed )
    speed -= 100; 
};
function decrease() {
  if(speed +100 <= minSpeed)      
    speed += 100;
};
```

Comment: this works like a charm, thank you. What if I wanted to put a cap on the amount so it would stop at a certain speed if increased or when decreased? @Infer-On

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
function playShow(playspeed) {
    timer = setTimeout('slideShow()', playspeed);
};
function increase() {

   var increase_to=10000;
   playshow(increase_to);

};
function decrease() {

    var decrease_to=100;
      playshow(decrease_to);
}
```